# Contactless heating of levitated tungsten

Tags: heat-transfer, metals, vacuum

I want to make a setup to melt tungsten. The best method I've come up with is using an induction heater to levitate and heat the tungsten, in a vacuum to prevent oxidation and limit heat transfer.

I've calculated the radiated heat from a 100g sphere of tungsten at its melting point to be about 7.7kW, assuming an emissivity of 0.5. Induction heaters that can supply that much power are [quite expensive](https://ussolid.com/u-s-solid-15-kw-high-frequency-induction-heater-30-80-khz-16-1-turns-ratio-220v-or-110v.html).

I thought of using a less powerful induction heater to levitate the tungsten and supplying most of the heat with some other method. Are there any other ways I can heat levitated tungsten in a vacuum?

Comment: CO2 laser .....

Comment: Can you change the shape of the tungsten object? E.g. if it's more like a cloud of wires or whiskers, microwaves might do the job by inducing melting currents for all those tiny diameters.

Comment: I don't think that would work, since once it starts to melt it'll clump together. Thin wires also have more surface area which would increase the radiated heat.

Comment: If you are melting tungsten, you probably have an objective beyond that; it should play a large role in your process.  Also consider that levitation and vacuum are not free- often times, the costs of achieving those conditions exceed the cost of energy you would have saved from them.